# Database Exception – yii\db\Exception : could not find driver

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, centos

I am working on Centos in Yii2. I have upgraded php 5.4 to php 7.1.19 but after upgrading it is showing me the error:

> Database Exception – yii\db\Exception could not find driver Caused by:
>   PDOException could not find driver

I have added config files in /etc/php.d and /usr/lib64/php/modules but it still gives me the same error.
I have checked using php -me the extension for pgsql is not available.

Any suggestion would be a great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with the installation files. Installing the following command did the job:  `yum install php-pgsql`